# Do I need to uninstall Java runtime environment before installing JDK?

Tags: java

I have an old version of Java runtime environment. Do I need to uninstall it before installing new JDK?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can have many JDKs and JREs installed in parallel. Just pay attention to

1. where your PATH environment variable points to
2. what's the value of the JAVA_HOME environment variable

Here's a [cross-platform reference](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Java+Environment+Variables+%282.6%29) to setting these variables (but beware, some of this may be project-specific, I just couldn't find any more canonical cross-platform document)

Comment: On windows they install java.exe also under windows\system32. So unless you run java using explicit path this what runs when you say `java`. So, be careful with this.

Comment: @AlexR you can circumvent that by setting the user path variables to `c:\myjdk\directory\bin;%PATH%`. Now your jdk bin directory has precedence over the System path.

Comment: Eventually you may want to clean up old versions of the JRE/JDK esp if you have dozens of them. However disk space is cheap these days ...

Comment: @Peter true, though you sometimes need to test how code works in an old JDK. (but hopefully I'll never ever ever again install a pre 1.5 JDK on any of my machines :-) )

Comment: True, one version JDK 1.4, 5.0, 6, 7 is not a head ache. It more a problem if you have installed every JDK 6 update 0 to update 23 etc ;)

Answer (score 0):

JDK includes JRE, located in the (JAVA_HOME)/jre directory. If you install JDK you do not need to additionally install another JRE.

Comment: True, but the question was the other way around :-)

Comment: Ooops, sorry! It is sometimes a "cleaner" approach to uninstall it. Just check to see if any old application depends on it.

Comment: Rename the old JRE directory and use your system for a while. If there are no complaints by any program, delete it. If there are, try to reconfigure the complaining application to work with the new JRE. If it is not possible rename it back an leave it.